# bootstrap datepicker duplication when using options and methods

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker), and I want to set options then apply some methods on the same datepicker, after reading the documentation of the plugin and tracked it, I faced duplication problem, the datepicker initialized twice.

```
var events = ['02/02/2015','02/05/2015','02/09/2015','03/09/2015'];

$('div').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true
});
$('div').datepicker('setDates', events);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/7/)

Comment: What do you mean it's initialized twice? Do 2 calendar popups show up?

Comment: yes, it's embedded datepicker, see fiddle example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/2L1ovhbm/7/) @D4V1D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a classname to the element and then apply the plugin:

Modified code from your jsFiddle:

```
var events = ['02/02/2015','02/05/2015','02/09/2015','03/09/2015'];

$('.date_picker').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    todayBtn: true        
});
$('.date_picker').datepicker('setDates', events);
$('tfoot .today').trigger('click');

$('.date_picker').on('changeDate', function(e){
  // extra 
  sdate = e.date.getDate() +'/'+ (e.date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + e.date.getFullYear();
  $('p').html(sdate);
  //window.location.href = 'events.html?date='+sdate;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="date_picker"></div>
```

And see if it works now.